# How would I make continuous functions to form these sets? Parametarizing of sets

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry, functions, continuity

How would I make continuous functions to form these sets?(So the domain is connected) I need continuous functions that map connected sets  to these in question.

$1. \text{Cone}$ $$(x,y,z)| \ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=\frac{z^2}{c^2}$$

I have in my notebook this function, but I am not sure if it only covers $z>0$ only or not:

$$(r,\varphi,z)\mapsto(r \cos \varphi,r\sin \varphi,z)$$

> I wish I could put this up for bounty right away, because I would, seeing as I have an exam coming up.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by continuous functions forming sets.

Comment: I edited, for clarity, hope it helps.

Comment: Why is the spherical coordinate function not what you are looking for?

Comment: I guess the first one is right. :D Now the other two are the problems, I dont know how to set a,b and c

Comment: In other words: how do I parametrize the following sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ellipsoid, compose $f$ with $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x\sqrt a,y\sqrt b,z\sqrt c)$.  For the cone, compose the cylindrical coordinates with I believe $(x,y,z)\mapsto(xz,yz,z)$.